# Make mass_assignment protection error not silent in Rails 3.2.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mass-assignment

This is a fairly simple thing, but since Rails 3.2 mass-assignment protection is enabled by default, is there a way to make rails raise an exception in dev or test when you try to set a protected attribute via mass assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in development.rb, the following is commented out by default. uncomment it.

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
```